# Functional programming in c#: how do I nest using statements and allow code blocks to modify returned data?

Tags: c#, generics, functional-programming, nested-generics

I am wrapping my head around functional programming in c# so I can lower the amount of side effects in my code as well as make testing easier and generalizing my code so refactoring can be easier. However, I have problems figuring out how to nest `using` statements using a generalized using block. Consider the following:

```
public static class Disposable
{
    public static TResult Using<TDisposable, TResult>
    (
      Func<TDisposable> factory,
      Func<TDisposable, TResult> fn) where TDisposable : IDisposable
      {
            using (var disposable = factory())
            {
                return fn(disposable);
            }
      }
}
```

I invoke this code by using the following code sample:

```
Disposable.Using(
               StreamFactory.GetStream,
               stream => new byte[stream.Length].Tee(b => stream.Read(b, 0, (int)stream.Length)))
```

and I pass the output of this modified `using` statement into another method in the pipeline.

I did however come across a caveat, where I am stuck.

***What if I want to use nested using statements, but make modifications to items returned that I want to pass along?***

Consider the following by reusing the `Disposable` class I stubbed above:

```
        Disposable.Using(
            () => new PasswordDeriveBytes(PasswordConstants.CryptoKey, null),
            password => Disposable.Using(
                () => new RijndaelManaged(),
                symmetricKey =>
                    Disposable.Using(
                        () => symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.KeySize/8), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.Cipher)),
                        encryptor => encryptor)
                ));
```

This code works... however, what if I wanted to change `symmetricKey's` encryption mode?

The following doesn't work:

```
        Disposable.Using(
                () => new PasswordDeriveBytes(PasswordConstants.CryptoKey, null),
                password => Disposable.Using(
                    () => new RijndaelManaged(),
                    symmetricKey =>
                        {
                            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; // ← this causes an issue, and also the fact that I made a **code block** here
                            Disposable.Using(
                                () => symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.KeySize/8), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.Cipher)),
                                encryptor => encryptor);
                        }
                    ));
```

What can I do to allow the modification of variables passed through the generalized `Disposable.Using` method I created above?

Comment: You have to `return` from your code block so it will match the `Func` signature.

Comment: I'm interested in how this improves your code - I can't so far see any difference from just using "using" blocks, which would I think be more concise and obvious. This invention of a new way of expressing the same thing seems like "syntactic vinegar" - but no doubt there's a good reason for it. If you can point me at a blog post or something that explains why you'd want to do this, I'd be grateful?

Comment: @GaryMcGill I have watched a few tutorials on pluralsight.com, which is on my work pc. I will link the courses to you, but from there on, you might need an account to watch it.

functional programming involves:
1 - Reducing side-effects in code
2 - improving testability
3 - allow method chaining (such as in F# pipelining and Javascript)
4 - Reducing codesmells 
5 - **making methods mathematical and honest** - you always know what goes into the method and what it returns by looking at the signature alone.

here is a sample site:
https://functionalcsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: @GaryMcGill Functional programming also promotes making your `valueobjects` immutable - if you need a change in a value, simply return a new reference. 

Also, with the solution provided by @juharr , the cyclomatic complexity of my method with the chained using statements dropped to 1 - suggesting that 1 unit test against the method will obtain 100% code coverage - but doesn't necessarily mean I only need to do one. I need to test what happens if I pass in a "null" for a password (as I am doing encryption in this method)

Comment: @Krohn: thanks. I get why functional programming is a worthwhile concept - and I'm totally on board with your numbered points - but I'm just not sure how it helps to wrap the existing "using" pattern in a function. It's not as though it limits what you can do, because as you demonstrated you can put an anonymous method in the 2nd parameter and mutate state there, so ultimately it's still down to the programmer to be rigorous about doing things the right way. Anyway, I'll take a look at the link you provided and see if a light goes on. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing a `return`.  Try this.

```
Disposable.Using(
    () => new PasswordDeriveBytes(PasswordConstants.CryptoKey, null),
    password => Disposable.Using(
        () => new RijndaelManaged(),
        symmetricKey =>
        {
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; 
            return Disposable.Using(
                () => symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.KeySize/8), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.Cipher)),
                encryptor => encryptor);
        }));
```

Comment: will do. it's going to be epic if it works, going to cut a 90 line method into like 10

Comment: @Krohn Really?  I have a hard time seeing how this would result in less code than just using regular `using` statements.

Comment: We have lots of spaghetti code. btw, this worked a charm!

Comment: I will probably extend the namespace where `disposable` resides with a `Tee` method which can pass through the value of a return and perform an action on it too, similar to unix console

Comment: @Krohn Wait, by returning the disposable object `encryptor` you're just going to get a disposed object, which seems pointless.  Or is there more nesting that you're not showing?

Comment: More nesting which I'm not showing. I showed code here as necessary

Answer (score 3):

> What if I want to use nested using statements, but make modifications to items returned that I want to pass along?

Let's start with simplifying your `Disposable.Using`, we do not need the generic `TDisposable` -- remove it and just use `IDisposable`.

```
public static class Disposable
{
    public static TResult Using<TResult>(
        Func<IDisposable> factory,
        Func<IDisposable, TResult> use)
   {
        using (var disposable = factory())
        {
             return use(disposable);
        }
   }
}
```

Also, as @juharr called attention to - you were missing a `return`:

```
Disposable.Using(
        () => new PasswordDeriveBytes(PasswordConstants.CryptoKey, null),
        password => Disposable.Using(
            () => new RijndaelManaged(),
            symmetricKey =>
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; 
                return Disposable.Using(
                    () => symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.KeySize/8), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PasswordConstants.Cipher)),
                    encryptor => encryptor);
            }));
```

This is due to the [subtle difference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one/) between `lambda` functions and `anonymous` methods.